# SharePoint site tagging

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, governance

I'm looking for a solution that can label the sites besides the Sensitivity labels.

I need to categorize all SharePoint sites and Teams Groups with a department "label" so it is just only and administrative tag on the site.

Since some Sensitivity labels are already used I need to make sure that I'm not messing around with them.